# Cant install polybar because python-xcbgen is not available

Tags: apt, python, i3-wm

I ran into dependency issue for polybar, I am using Ubuntu20.04. `apt-get install` gave me the following error:

```
Package python-xcbgen is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-xcbgen' has no installation candidate
```

Then I tried `sudo apt-get install python3-xcbgen`, which successfully installed (v 1.14-2). However, polybar installation still complained it couldn't find python-xcbgen.

I am using Anaconda python so I dont know if it has anything to do with it.

Please advice. Thanks

Comment: From where did you try to install polybar? It's in the Ubuntu archive only in groovy, and there is depends on `python3-xcbgen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building polybar does not seem to work well with anaconda. The recommended way is to either uninstall it or completely disable it while building polybar.

From the [Known Issues](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Known-Issues#building-with-anaconda-installed) polybar wiki page:

> Problem: On systems using Anaconda compiling polybar will likely fail
>   with one of these error messages:
>
> - `Missing required python module: xcbgen`
> - `ERROR: could not calc required_start_align of Struct "xcb.Setup"`
> - `Cairo was not compiled with support for the xcb backend`
>
> The general issue is that the libraries and programs provided by
>   Anaconda cannot be used to build polybar in many cases.
>
> Fix: The easiest fix is to uninstall Anaconda if you don't need it.
>
> If you can't/don't want to uninstall Anaconda, we need to force
>   polybar to not use any resources provided by Anaconda. This can be
>   done by temporarily removing any paths that point to anaconda from
>   both the $PATH and $PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variables in the
>   terminal before building polybar.
>
> People have reported that conda deactivate does that for you for the
>   currently open terminal. If that doesn't work, try doing it manually:
>
> For example if your PATH variable contains:
>
> /home//anaconda2/bin:/home//bin:...:/usr/bin
>
> Remove /home//anaconda2/bin and reexport the variable:
>
> export PATH=/home//bin:...:/usr/bin
>
> Do the same thing for PKG_CONFIG_PATH (though this variable is often
>   already empty). Now you should be able to build polybar with either
>   the build.sh script or cmake and make. Make sure that you do a clean
>   build (redownload all polybar sources).

The last sentence is very important. You must do a clean build. This means deleting the polybar sources that you downloaded and redownloading them.

Comment: thank you ! This is great info. I can disable anaconda and just use the buildin python to install it.